# Scan logic errors UNITY C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am developing a scan system on Unity for Vive Focus 3, hand tracking, Wave XR 5.3.2, all plugins related installed although here I think it must be a logic issue because hardware is working relatively fine otherwise
My timeline keeps getting stuck on a scanning state and the system stops detecting hand gestures at some point

```
    {
        if (handType == hand && otherHand.scanState == ScanState.NotScanning && timerBetweenGestureToggles == timeBetweenGestureToggles)
        {
            timerBetweenGestureToggles = 0f;

            if (scanState == ScanState.NotScanning || coolingDown)
            {
                ScanGestureDetected(handType);
            } 
            else
            {
                ExitScanGestureDetected(handType);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ExitScanGestureDetected(HandManager.HandType? handType)
    {
        if (handType == hand)
        {
            timer = scanGestureNotDetectedCooldown;

            coolingDown = true;
        }
    }

    private void ScanGestureDetected(HandManager.HandType? handType)
    {
        if (handType == hand && otherHand.scanState == ScanState.NotScanning)
        {
            if (coolingDown)
                coolingDown = false;
            else
                scanState = ScanState.WarmupScan;
        }
    }
```

I believe a logic error in transition state to be the mistake but can't figure out the answer

Comment: That's way too much not-well formatted code - nobody will take a look at it. Can you reduce it to the most relevant part?

Comment: Alright thanks, reduced to what I thought might be the problematic/most relevant part in my case.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] .. I think now it is reduced too much